# How to do API testing with Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I am learning Puppeteer. Just out of curosity, is it possible to test an API using Puppeteer, e.g. I call my api endpoint and intercept response.

Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't you just call the endpoint using HTTP?

Comment: How can i test, status-code, content header etc.